# how to remove (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false?

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

what is the meaning of this log message? how to remove it?

```
 I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

it is flooding my log.

Answer (score 2):

The message is an INFO level log entry, created by a Samsung http library class called "SBServiceAPI", and that sends it to System.out. So, a way to remove these messages is as follows:

Add this line e.g. to your onCreate method:

```
System.setOut(new FilteringPrintStream(System.out));
```

And add this class to your project:

```
public class FilteringPrintStream extends PrintStream {

    public FilteringPrintStream(OutputStream out)  {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(String x) {
        if (x==null || !x.contains("isSBSettingEnabled")) {
            super.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```